# Remove Random Movement from div Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using a plugin that makes a div move randomly. I'd like it however, to move (up and down, left and right) to specific parts of my page.

You'd find the fiddle below, I'd appreciate your help
http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/15/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the location of your element, and animate to that

Create a function that finds the location of your desired elements.

```
function makeCustomJPosition(){
var myElement = //your element

$('.a').animate({ top: myElement.ywhatever, left: myElement.xwhatever }, speed, function(){
  animateDiv();        
});
```

}